# Custom Collection Implementing IEnumerable

Tags: c#, interface, ienumerable, yield

I know that technically, an Interface is used for reading and not writting or editing however, I want to add an add and addrange function to the following class, here is what I currently have which is not working

```
public class HrefCollection : IEnumerable<Href> 
{
    private IEnumerable<Href> hrefs;

    public IEnumerable<Href> Add( Href href )
    {
        yield return href;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Href> AddRange( List<Href> hrefs )
    {
        foreach( Href href in hrefs )
        {
            yield return href;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<Href> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return hrefs.GetEnumerator();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return hrefs.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

I'm not quite sure how to associate the yield return with the private list.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You may be a little confused here.  Is there a reason for you not to simply use a List<Href>?

Comment: "an Interface is used for reading and not writting or editing" ?? I don't understand that statement. You mean IEnumerable?

Comment: I kinda misexplained, I mean that The Ienumerable interface does not contain an "add" method because it's used for returning objects from the current collection not for adding or removing something from it.

Comment: I dont want to use List (even though I could implement IList), I want to use  yield return and kinda understand how it works and how i can use it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerable` interfaces are used to generate a read-only sequence or provide a read-only view of the items in a collection.

If you want to be able to add items to your collection then, internally, you'll need to use a data structure that allows items to be added -- for example `List<T>`. You simply can't add items using the `IEnumerable<T>` or `IEnumerable` interfaces.

```
public class HrefCollection : IEnumerable<Href>
{
    private readonly List<Href> _hrefs = new List<Href>();

    public void Add(Href href)
    {
        _hrefs.Add(href);
    }

    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<Href> hrefs)
    {
        _hrefs.AddRange(hrefs);
    }

    public IEnumerator<Href> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _hrefs.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable)_hrefs).GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, but it's still pretty silly and it doesn't serve the purpose of learning how yield works.

Comment: @tehMick: True, but the question says "I want to add an add and addrange function to the following class". I know that the question also mentions using `yield return`, but the answer is that you just can't use `yield return` to add items to a collection.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach( Href href in hrefs )
{
    yield return href;
}
```

should be

```
foreach( Href href in this.hrefs )
{
    yield return href;
}
foreach( Href href in hrefs )
{
    yield return href;
}
```

Comment: @Burnzy: could you be more specific?

Comment: well if I call addrange, the Collection remains null.

Comment: Actually, you should get rid of the private IEnumerable<Href> hrefs;
.  You're declaring one IEnumerable<Href> inside another.  Instead, you should be referencing this.

Comment: @Burzy, but using yield will never add to the collection you have, only output a new collection.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class HrefCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>  {


// access via this[index]
}
```